# Image resize to a specific height and width in django python

Tags: python, django, image, crop

I have a django based website in which I have created profiles of people working in the organisation. Since this is a redesign effort, I used the already **existing** profile pictures. The size of current profile image  style is 170x190px. Since the images already exist and are of different sizes, I want to crop them to the size specified above. But how do I decide from which side I have to crop?

Currently, I have applied style of 170by190 to all the images while displaying in profiles, but most of them look distorted as the **aspect ratios do not match**.

I have tried PIL thumbnail function but it does not fit the need.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to resize pictures, but images ratio create huge impact on final result. As images have some ratio, and you cannot simply resize them to 170px190px without prior adjusting of their ratio, so you have **to update( not crop them!)** images before resizing them to get best possible output, it can be done in next ways:

1. Crop them manually to desired ratio (17:19). **(take a while if you have plenty of images)**
2. Create script which add padding to that images if image ratio is close to required, all images which ratio is far away from desired mark as 'human cropping required' and work with their ratio later by own **(semi-manual, so still may be really time consuming)**
3. Spend some time and write face recognation function, then process images with that function and find faces, then crop them from origin image, but before: add  padding to achieve desired radio (17:19) at top and bottom of face. **(recommended)**

Some links which may be use full for you:

- [Face Recognition With Python, in Under 25 Lines of Code](https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-recognition-with-python/)
- [facereclib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/facereclib) module, they probably are able to help you.
- [Image Manipulation, The Hitchhiker’s Guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/imaging/)

**Good luck !**

Comment: Thanks, I will try out these options.

Comment: @escapee you are welcome :) hope you would do it easily.

Comment: I have worked on a kind of crude method. What I have tried is resizing images to 170width or 190 height, depending on the aspect ratio is bigger than 1 or smaller than 1. and then cropping width/height. It has worked for most of the images. And I have also given image resizing option while updating the photo at user end.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sorl-thumbnail](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), you don't need to crop every image manually.